# Trying to get 1:1 NAT working with OpenVPN (Layer 2 tap tunnel)

Tags: ubuntu, debian, iptables, nat

All. I have a small project which needs to have everything in the same collision domain (Layer 2). I was wondering which iptables commands I would need to run in order to get the printer (192.168.192.11/24) to be visible on the OpenVPN tap0 (10.0.0.51/24) device via a 1:1 NAT. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Basically, it looks like the following:

[image: Small Diagram of Network]

Basically, I have a printer (192.168.192.11/24) on the same network as an Ubuntu Server or Debian (192.168.192.253/24 eth0) which doesn't have a gateway assigned. It's then dual-homed to another network that does have Internet access (192.168.11.x/24 eth1) with a gateway at 192.168.11.1/24. On that network, there is also an OpenVPN tap tunnel created with an IP of 10.0.0.51/24.

Hopefully, this explains what I would like to do. Any help or comments greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Thanks in advance.